# How do I calculate P->Q: an Arc of a circle?

Tags: trigonometry, programming

**How do I calculate the arc of a circle in radions?**

Hi there! It has been many years since I have brushed up on my trigonometry skills, and I am trying to solve this particular equation for my program at work.

[image: Here is the picture I drew of the problem]

- The radius of the Big circle is **known**: R1
- The radius of the small circle is **known**: R2
- The the x, y coordinates of point P is **known**
- The the x, y coordinates of point P2 is **known**
- The the x, y coordinates of point P3 is **known**
- The the x, y coordinates of point Q is **unknown**

---

**What I actually want to solve**

I want to know what is the distance in *radians* following the the arc of the big circle from point **P** to **Q**? Could someone please show me how to solve this step by step, explaining each of the steps as they go?

If I need to be clearer explaining the problem or give more information, I will happily provide it.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be the center of the small circle. Its $x$ coordinate must be $x_{P3}+r_2$.

Its $y$ coordinate is such that the distance $P_2C$ is $r_1-r_2$. So you can write down an equation for it:
$$ (x_{P3}+r_2-x_{P2})^2 + (y_C-y_{P2})^2 = (r_1-r_2)^2 $$
which is easy enough solve for $y_C$:
$$ y_C = y_{P2} + \sqrt{(r_1-r_2)^2-(x_{P3}+r_2-x_{P2})^2} $$

Now that you know the coordinates of $C$ you can compute the *direction* from $P_2$ to $C$ (which is also the direction from $P_2$ to $Q$) by a single `atan2` operation.

You can also compute the direction from $P_2$ to $P$ by `atan2`.

The difference between those direction is the central angle between $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: Shouldn't "You can also compute the direction from P2 to P3 by atan2." be P2 to P to compute the angle P P2 Q?

Comment: @miguel.martin: Whoops, you're right -- typo fixed.

Comment: On second thought, finding $y_C$ explicitly is a detour; we can just find the direction towards $C$ (and $Q$) as $$\arccos \Bigl(\frac{(x_{P3}+r_2)-x_{P2}}{r_1-r_2}\Bigr)$$